Who are these characters in "My Adventures with Superman"?
In My Adventures with Superman S2E6, Superman fights certain robots illusioned as beings from different planets. What are these beings, and to which planets do they belong? One of these beings was using a Green Lantern ring.


From left to right, they are a Parademon, an unidentified Green Lantern wielder, and a Thanagarian. Unfortunately, I haven't found an official statement of this, but the sacking of Thanagar was shown in the episode, and statements online seem fairly universal as to the origin of those foes, all indicated to be representatives of conquered races.
